# Shell script to run each command from script in different terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, maven, unix

As I am new to Linux and using ubuntu and I want help to write a script which will be having multiple commands and for each command a respective terminal should be opened and execute the command.

As I have written a script which having commands like:

> `mvn tomcat:run -Dmaven.tomcat.port=8081`
>
> `mvn tomcat:run -Dmaven.tomcat.port=8181`

So all these two command should be run in different terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your Linux flavor there are a number of different terminals available, each of which has a potentially different mechanism for specifying a command.

However, it's pretty likely your Linux will have an xterm which will use a '-e' flag and take a command

e.g.

```
xterm -e "mvn tomcat:run -Dmaven.tomcat.port=8081"
```

For Ubuntu you can try

```
gnome-terminal -e "mvn tomcat:run -Dmaven.tomcat.port=808"
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Just for curiosity wanted to ask what is the command to open the default terminal of Ubuntu.

Comment: works but faced another problem, the new terminal doesn't hold it starts and closes immediately. Please help.

Comment: @Ravi `xterm -e "mvn tomcat:run -Dmaven.tomcat.port=8081; read -p 'Command died. Press enter to close this terminal'"`